# .NET 4 (WinForms) Dynamic Form Control Creation in Powershell

Tags: winforms, powershell

I am trying to dynamically add form controls to a gui I'm developing in PowerShell.  I have looked at VB and C# examples but can't seem to get my form to actually populate the gui with a new control.  What I want is to be able to append a potentially large number of additional controls to the form and the added controls get dumped into a scrollable field so they don't end up off the end of the gui.  How I tried to accomplish this is append a combobox to a tablelayoutpanel.  My idea being, adding a new row to the tablelayoutpanel with a new combobox control would accomplish this.  So I suppose I have two questions:

1. Is this the logically correct way of going about dynamically adding controls to an object that will allow for scrollable overflow?
2. If #1 is true, how do I accomplish this tasK?

This is the most recent iteration of my attempts:

```
$button1_Click={
    $new = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    Add-ComboBox $rowCount
    $rowCount++
}

function Add-ComboBox {
    param([string] $rowCount)
    $combobox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
    $combobox.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill
    $combobox.Text = ""
    $combobox.Tag = "ComboBox$rowCount"
    $tablelayoutpanel1.Controls.Add($combobox, 1, $rowCount)
}
```

Your assistance is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer on the Microsoft Technet forums.  A forum moderator has been helping me out with this.  Thanks though!

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/b2c8abeb-3ae6-4936-9bef-a50a79fdff45/

Answer (score 1):

This might be useful, though it's WPF, the snippet creates a window with a few buttons on it that resizes depending on how many buttons are added to the StackPanel

```
$window = new-object System.Windows.Window
$stackPanel = new-object System.Windows.Controls.StackPanel

$buttonNum = 20
for( $i = 0; $i -lt $buttonNum; $i++ )
{
    $button = new-object System.Windows.Controls.Button
    $button.Content = "Button Text" + $i
    $stackPanel.Children.Add( $button )
}

$scrollViewer = new-object System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer
$scrollViewer.Content = $stackPanel
$window.Content = $scrollViewer

$window.SizeToContent = [System.Windows.SizeToContent]::Width
$window.Height = 100
$window.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I was using Windows PowerShell ISE 2.0 on Windows 7

Comment: and you used JUST this code to accomplish what I described?? when I run the code, I get errors about calling methods on Null objects.