# Dynamic Windows Form Control Creation - General Question

Tags: c#, winforms, powershell

I'm working with a GUI in PowerShell and trying to make the form such that, after the form is built, the user can interact with the part of the form (+/- button) to dynamically add a group of controls to the form underneath of the existing set.

As an example, there will be a combobox (drop-down) to select a parameter and then a text field to fill in the value for the selected parameter.

What I'm looking for is a way to dynamically add that group of controls to the form when the user clicks the plus button.  My current attempts have failed.  I've tried pinning the controls inside of a TableLayoutPanel and a Panel object but can't seem to get the items to appear in the first place and then appear in some semblence of order.  Is there a GUI object that I can pin the controls to that will just auto-dump the next row of controls below the existing or do I have to figure out the calculations off of the docked parent and offset the Y-values?

Does anyone know a PowerShell accessible Windows form control that would support this type of additions?

One of my attempts is psoted here:  [.NET 4 (WinForms) Dynamic Form Control Creation in Powershell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6231562/net-4-winforms-dynamic-form-control-creation-in-powershell)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the answer from a Microsoft PowerShell forum Moderator:

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/ITCG/thread/b2c8abeb-3ae6-4936-9bef-a50a79fdff45/

it's the datagridview object that needs to be used.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use FlowLayoutPanel. [Here](http://www.sapien.com/forums/scriptinganswers/forum_posts.asp?TID=1694) is the sample script for using FlowLayoutPanel in Powershell

Answer (score 1):

It's not Winforms, but there is a new module up on Codeplex called ShowUI, which enables you to create WPF based UI's in PowerShell. Take a look at http://showui.codeplex.com. There is some examples up there on using Grid controls and automatic layouts, that I think could meet your needs if you are willing to jump into WPF.

Comment: creating the UI isn't the problem, dynamically generating form controls (and my understanding of it), is.  I have an existing gui, i'm just trying to extend it.

Answer (score 0):

Can't you simply build your form (for example with Sapiens free editor tool) with all the controls invisible, and then according to the user choice make them visible ?

Comment: I'm using Sapien's PrimalScript 2011 Studio -- that's not the problem.  I'm trying to have the gui grab all the properties from a specific object and then dynamically build a line that consists of a combobox, and textbox.  The combo box consists of all properties returned so the user can select the property and then fill in the value to build the command-line.  Then, they can hit a + button which dynamically generates another line (under the previous one(s)) so they can fill out another property/textbox combo.